# React slingshot - Webpack hot middleware returning 404 on hot-update.json when using react router sub-routes

Tags: webpack, react-router, react-slingshot

Im using the react slingshot starter project for my react/redux app. Hot reload works great when I use routes like `/foo` but I've found that hot reload isn't working on subroutes like `/foo/bar`. I haven't made any changes to the out-of-the-box webpack config file, which can be found here https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/webpack.config.js

I get `404 GET http://localhost:3004/orders/c344e97ed1fbc2923017.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)`on the CreateOrder component when I have the following routes configuration:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="orders" component={OrderPanel} />
    <Route path="orders/create" component={CreateOrder} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Route>
```

But when I change the path from orders/create to just create, it doesn't returns a 404.

It seems like the hot update middleware is trying to fetch the hot-update.json from the /orders subroute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness and anyone having this problem with an older version of slingshot.
This was also mentioned in [issue 75](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/75) and fixed [here](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/commit/386026a9cc9e03a7333dc86b8f7e02efb0f850ac) by replacing:

```
publicPath: '',
```

with

```
publicPath: '/',
```

in `webpack.config.js`

UPDATE:
From reduckted's comment the publicPath has to start and end with a slash. Replace:

```
publicPath: 'dist/',
```

with

```
publicPath: '/dist/',
```

Comment: Had a similar issue. I already had a public path ending with a slash. I fixed it by also making the public path _start_ with a slash. For example, I had `publicPath: 'dist/'`, but had to change it to `publicPath: '/dist/'`.

Comment: @reduckted I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

publicPath config wasn't an issue for me.
If you are using redux can try this.

For some random reason `redux-devtools` was not allowing hot reload for me. Try removing it from root component and `redux compose` config.

Note: Use redux devtool browser extension with this config in your store configuration: `window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f`

Also, must read: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpacks-hmr-react-hot-loader-the-missing-manual-232336dc0d96#.ejpsmve8f

Or try hot reload 3: 
example: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915